# XSLT transform source xml elements into multiple different target xml elements

Tags: xml, xslt

The title of this post does not explain clearly what I am trying to do. I think an example will explain it best. I have a source xml document as follows:

```xml
<x>
   <a>some data 1</a>
   <a>some data 2</a> 
   <a>some data 3</a> 
   <a>some not needed data 4</a> 
   <a>some not needed data 5</a> 
</x>
```

I need to transform this into certain `<a>` elements (in this example let's say the ones whose value is "some data x") have to be put into one section (starting section), but since this section can only hold 2 elements, the rest have to be put into another section (ending section). In between these two sections there are other unrelated elements. For example:

```xml
<starting>
   <a>some data 1</a>
   <a>some data 2</a> 
</starting>
<someOtherXmlElements/>
<someMoreOtherXmlElements/>
<ending>
   <a>some data 3</a> 
</ending>
```

I have the logic in a template which figures out which elements (again in this example, the ones whose value is "some data x") of the whole set I need to pull.
The problem is that when I am processing in the  element, there is no way for me to tell which elements are already in the  element.
This would be a piece of cake if I could update variables, but unfortunately XSLT does not allow that.
Any suggestions?
The output scheme cannot be changed by the way.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't terribly elegant, but it does the job. It uses xslt version 1.0. I tested it with msxsl.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
                exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl" version="1.0"
                >
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">

    <root>
    <starting>
      <xsl:for-each select="/x/a[substring(text(), 1, 9)='some data']">
        <xsl:if test="position() = 1 or position() = 2">
          <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
          </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </starting>

    <someOtherXmlElements/>
    <someMoreOtherXmlElements/>
    <ending>
      <xsl:for-each select="/x/a[substring(text(), 1, 9)='some data']">
        <xsl:if test="position() &gt; 2">
          <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
          </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </ending>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I got this output:

```
<root>
  <starting>
    <a>some data 1</a>
    <a>some data 2</a>
  </starting>
  <someOtherXmlElements />
  <someMoreOtherXmlElements />
  <ending>
    <a>some data 3</a>
  </ending>
</root>
```